# Android Error:(20, 8) error: Fragment is not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I am new to android and i have been trying this bit of code but i am getting the following error:
Error:(20, 8) error: SyllabusFragment is not abstract and does not override abstract method createAssignmentClicked(Assignment) in onCreateInteractionListener

I am not able to understand whats wrong with my code
Any help would be appreciated

SyllabusFragment:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class SyllabusFragment  extends Fragment
    implements ColorDialogFragment.onCreateInteractionListener,
    CreateAssignmentDialogFragment.onCreateInteractionListener,
    classFragment.assignmentCall,
    EditClassDialogFragment.onEditListener,
    EditAssignmentDialogFragment.onEditListener,
    EditColorDialogFragment.onCreateInteractionListener{

private String currentClass;
/*  Function returns the current parent class of activities being displayed. To only be called
 *  when a assignment fragment is being displayed.*/
public String getParentClass() {
    return currentClass;
}

/* Definition variables, indicating a certain fragment. */
private static final int CLASS_LIST_VIEW = 0;
private static final int ASSIGNMENT_LIST_VIEW = 1;

/* Variable, that is changed depending on which fragment is being displayed. */
private int currentFragment;
/*  A function which receives no arguments. Returns an integer value, indicating which fragment
 *  is being displayed within the activity. */
public int getCurrentFragment() {
    return currentFragment;
}

/*  A function that is called when a new fragment is being displayed, which sets the title of
 *  the activity, as well as sets the currentFragment variable to its proper value. */
public void setCurrentFragment(int fragment) {
    switch (fragment) {
        case CLASS_LIST_VIEW:
            currentFragment = fragment;
            //setTitle("Simple Planner");
            break;
        case ASSIGNMENT_LIST_VIEW:
            currentFragment = fragment;
            /*  Setting activity title to the parent class of the assignments being displayed. */
           // setTitle(getParentClass());
            break;
    }
}

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_syllabus, container, false);

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    //if (!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {
    // <---- run your one time code here();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, prefs.getInt("hour", 19));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, prefs.getInt("minute", 30));
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), AlaramReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) SyllabusFragment.this.getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);
    //}

    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);

     /* Creating listener for Floating Action Button. */
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /* Action for when Floating Action Button is clicked. */
            switch (getCurrentFragment()) {
                case CLASS_LIST_VIEW: {
                    DialogFragment dialogFragment = new CreateClassDialogFragment();
                    dialogFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
                    break;
                }
                case ASSIGNMENT_LIST_VIEW: {
                    DialogFragment dialogFragment = new CreateAssignmentDialogFragment();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("parent_class", getParentClass());
                    dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
                    dialogFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
     /* Creating initial fragment, containing the list view for all of the classes registered. */
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment, classFragment.newInstance());
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
    setCurrentFragment(CLASS_LIST_VIEW);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void assignmentCallMethod(String pClass) {
    /* A class was clicked. Changing the fragment to the assignment fragment. */
    currentClass = pClass;
    FragmentTransaction transaction =getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit);
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, assignmentsFragment.newInstance(pClass));
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
    setCurrentFragment(ASSIGNMENT_LIST_VIEW);
}

/* Function that is called from the create class fragment. */
@Override
public void createClicked() {
    /* A new class was created. Recreating the class view fragment. */
    FragmentTransaction transaction =getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit, R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, classFragment.newInstance());
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
@Override
public void editClassMethod() {
    /* A new class was edited. Recreating the class view fragment. */
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit, R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, classFragment.newInstance());
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}



@Override
public void editAssignmentMethod(int c) {
    switch (c) {
        case 0:
            FragmentTransaction transaction =getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit);
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, assignmentsFragment.newInstance(getParentClass()));
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            break;
        case 1:
    }
}
 //   @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentTransaction transaction;
    switch (getCurrentFragment()) {
        /* If viewing the class view, close the app. */
        case CLASS_LIST_VIEW:
            getActivity().finish();
            return;
        /* If viewing an assignment, return to the class view. */
        case ASSIGNMENT_LIST_VIEW:
            transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit, R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, classFragment.newInstance());
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            setCurrentFragment(CLASS_LIST_VIEW);
            break;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Abstract classes are allowed to be just that, abstract. They don't have to follow the rigid guidelines of their super class/interfaces. You are saying that you implement onCreateActionListener, but you aren't overriding the method in your class anywhere that actually makes that true, nor are you declaring your method abstract to get past that requirement. Add the `createAssignmentClicked(Assignment)` method to your class or get rid of the interface declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you are implementing the interface **CreateAssignmentDialogFragment** but you are not overriding the method **onCreateInteractionListener(Assingment)** from this interface, in order to use the interface you have to override that method.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that if your fragment  implements ColorDialogFragment.onCreateInteractionListener it must implement createAssignmentClicked(Assignment).